# Why UIView.animate performs different result on view.layer and sublayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation, calayer

Here is my code:

```swift
        let colorLayer = CALayer()
        colorLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        colorLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        let blockView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        blockView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(blockView)

        blockView.layer.addSublayer(colorLayer)

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true, block: { (t) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) { [self] in
                // this animation lasts 1s
//                let transform = blockView.layer.affineTransform()
//                blockView.layer.setAffineTransform(transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2.0)))
                // while this animation 0.25s
                let transform2 = colorLayer.affineTransform()
                colorLayer.setAffineTransform(transform2.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2.0)))
            } completion: { (complete) in

            }

        })
```

Why my custom sublayer `colorLayer` rotates by 0.25s (default value), not set by `withDuration:` parameter, but `blockView.layer` works fine?

Answer (score 0):

UIView animations are meant to animate changes to animatable properties of UIView objects. They are not meant to animate CALayer properties.

Your code to change the colorLayer is probably not being animated by the UIView animation call at all. It is just that a CALayer's transform property supports implicit animations, so changing it triggers an implicit animation. I would expect that line to have exactly the same effect outside of a UIView animation.

I suspect that your call to apply an affine transform to your block view works because it ends changing the same transform property that you would change by using code like

```
blockView.transform = blockView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2.0)
```

The short answer: Don't try to animate layer properties using UIView animation. It usually doesn't work.